# Remove numeric part of string with length 5 or more digits

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have `NSString` (some city location in Mexico) that includes a zip code in front of it. A zip code is **always** 5 digits.

`81124 Corerepe, Sin.`

I need to remove that zip code, remove a DIGIT part of that string but **ONLY if that number is 5 Digits in length or Greater**. It was an easy task in Java (android) but in XCode ... seems like no one has ever done that before...

Can anyone help me please,

Thank you.

Comment: That's just the matter of using `String`'s `components(separatedBy:)` and counting the number of letters for the first component, right?

Comment: Here: `string.replaceAll("\\d{5}", "")` - this is from Java. It's basically removing digits - ONLY if 5 of them in the row. I need the same in Objective-C. B

Comment: Show what you have done.

Comment: Well, I haven't done anything cuz I couldn't find this one line of code with the function(s) that do what I need.

Comment: There is no function that removes the first five digits if they are numbers. You have to write your own. How did you do it in Java?

Comment: Google "NSString regular expression"

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want an equivalent of `string.replaceAll("\\d{5}", "")`.
I don't use Java, but I guess that there is a `NSRegularExpression`. Note, that I would have used `^\\d{5}` instead, because `81124 Corerepe, 12345 Sin.` would have output  `Corerepe,  Sin.`.

Objective-C Equivalent would be:

```
NSMutableString *address = [@"81124 Corerepe, 12345 Sin." mutableCopy];
[address replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"^\\d{5}" withString:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [address length])];
NSLog(@"Address: %@", address);
```

Output:

```
$>Address:  Corerepe, 12345 Sin.
```

Side note, I would have even used `@"^\\d{5}\\s*"`, to remove also the white space.

Comment: This is it. You nailed it. Just one tiny adjustment I made was removing `^` - that way if the zip code appears to be anywhere in the middle of the string, then it's still going to be removed. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok, I thought only at the beginning. But `{5}` doesn't manage if it's more than 5 digits, right? You might want `{5,}`

Comment: Ok. That's an interesting point. Postal codes in Russia are 6 digits and there are only digits. I think a more difficult task would be to recognize a Canadian postal code - most complicated ever - V3C8E6 - alternate letter, number, and 6 chars.